# Select with date

Tags: java, sql, database, syntax

I select `Registered_Date` in my database like below :

```
Select Count(Registered_Date) AS DATE
from Patient_Records
where Registered_Date >= '09-01-2018'
```

and I have (3) of '09-25-2018' on my `Patient_Records` but it also including the '09-15-2017' how can I select also the year?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: your question is not much clear ,could you please explain what you need as a output

Comment: I suspect that your `Registered_Date` is a `varchar` column, so `>=` operation compares two strings, and then `09-15-2017` is indeed lexically "greater" than `09-25-2018`. Only solution you have here to have it work like you expect is to use `date` or `timestamp` column instead of `varchar` (assuming your rdbms allows for it).

Comment: I mistyped: `09-15-2017` is greater than `09-01-2018` when comparing strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DBMS hasn’t got a `date` datatype and you need to store strings, then store strings in ISO 8601 format, like `2018-09-15` (yyyy-mm-dd). This will make sure that comparisons with `<` and `>` give you “before” and “after”.

Link: [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 1):

Datatype of your Registered_Date must be varchar or text, hence mysql is sorting it lexicographically and not according to date.

Please change your datatype to any of the date formats like TIMESTAMP() and your problem will be solved